# moving user controller logic into model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using a gem called stripe_connect, which is an Oauth2 solution for Stripe. Now currently this code works fine, it's semi-repetitive when it comes to

```
request.env['omniauth.auth']
```

but beside that I think it looks okay. However I do wish to move this out of my controller and into the model. However I'm not exactly sure on how to make the transition. Would anybody be able to be of assistance?

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def stripe_connect
    @user = current_user
    if @user.update_attributes(
      provider: request.env['omniauth.auth'].provider,
      uid: request.env['omniauth.auth'].uid,
      access_code: request.env['omniauth.auth'].credentials.token,
      publishable_key: request.env['omniauth.auth'].info.stripe_publishable_key
    )
      redirect_to rooms_path
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: 'Stripe') if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session['devise.stripe_connect_data'] = request.env['omniauth.auth']
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the update attribute portion of code to model to make the controller code look clean and readable:

**CONTROLLER**

call it as `@user.update_oauth_details(request)` (Or any other name)

**MODEL** (**User**)

```
def update_oauth_details(request)
  self.update_attributes(
    provider: request.env['omniauth.auth'].provider,
    uid: request.env['omniauth.auth'].uid,
    access_code: request.env['omniauth.auth'].credentials.token,
    publishable_key: request.env['omniauth.auth'].info.stripe_publishable_key
    )
end
```